# AngularJS display object in HTML

Tags: angularjs, laravel, api, ionic-framework

i've made an api call to retrieve some data. succesfully.
It;s a sum of total hours of credits..i retrieve

Laravel SQL query:

```
$result = DB::table('contracts')
    ->select(DB::raw('SUM(monthly_credits) as Total'))
    ->get();
    return $this->sendResponse($result->toArray(), 'credits retrieved succesfully');
```

Angular call:

```
 monthlyCredits() {
return new Promise(resolve => {
  this.http.get(this.apiUrl+'/api/credits').subscribe(data => {
    resolve(data);},
    err => {
      console.log(err);
  });
});
```

}

home.ts:

```
  monthlyCredits(){
this.restProvider.monthlyCredits()
.then(data => {
this.credits = data['data'];
console.log(this.credits);
});
```

}

data: [{total: 50.5}]
-> 0: {total: 50.5}

As i display it on the frond-end with `{{credits | json }}`

it returns

[{"total":50.5}]

Im trying to only display the sum of the total credits, which is 50.5. not the other characters.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You need to access the total property from the credits, change it as follows,

```
{{credits[0].total}}
```

Comment: when i try that, it displays nothing. :(

Comment: try to access with index 0 as above

Comment: probably it is not loaded at this state, try setting in home.ts as described in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the `total` to your `this.credits` or you have to use the fullpath within your html template like `{{credits[0].total}}`

try following in your home.ts:

```
  monthlyCredits(){
this.restProvider.monthlyCredits()
.then(data => {
this.credits = data['data'][0]['total'];
console.log(this.credits);
});
```

Make sure you access total only if it is loaded.